# Using a model with a dynamic model in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mvcsitemapprovider

I am a front end developer and not very strong with MVC 4, so I apologise if this is a very stupid question.

I am attempting to modify a view I have inherited - I have copied a dynamic model into a page that has a model already - I know that you cannot have 2 models declared, so how should I modify the below?

```
@model MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models.SiteMapNodeModel
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@using MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models
@using Project.RealTime.LookupService;
@using Project.RealTime.Models;
@model dynamic
@{
    SessionVars session = new SessionVars();
    Account account = null;
    if ((Model != null) && (Model is Account))
    {
        account = (Account)Model;
    }
```

What is the best way to combine the model and the dynamic model so I can use both in this view?

Answer (score 0):

Try to leave just `@model dynamic` and delete `@model MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models.SiteMapNodeModel`.

But it will be better to have two separate views with strongly-typed models. Because it helps you to identify some errors at compile time and have intellisense on view.

If you need Account in our view - maybe you should review your ViewModel and add Account to it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can only have one Model in the View, the best option is to modify the Model so that it includes the information in your new `dynamic` model.

You have two good options:

-Edit the existing Model class and add the properties

-Or inherit the existing Model:

```
public class MyNamespace.MyNewModel : MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models.SiteMapNodeModel
    {
         public string Property1 { get; set; }
         /* .... */
    }
```

And in your View only reference the new View Model:

```
@model MyNamespace.MyNewModel
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot modify the `SiteMapNodeModel` - it is part of the MVCSiteMapProvider which is a NuGet package and is compiled.

Comment: Then use the example code I provided. You should be able to inherit the existing model and add your properties that way.

Comment: Inheriting the old Model and adding new properties will let you access properties from both the old model and your new one.

Comment: I'm really sorry - I'm having some trouble understanding this.  I'll keep playing with it and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Include the dynamic data you want into the model. A model should usually not be a certain data class but rather a class that is a collection of the data to be used in your view.

For example

```
public class ControllerActionViewModel
{
    public FooClass Foo;
    public dynamic Foo2;
}
```

and then

```
@model Project.Models.ControllerActionViewModel

@Model.Foo2.whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is using the ViewBag for the dyanmic part. ViewBag is a dynamic object which is available in both the controller and the template. If you add a property in the controller, it will be available in the template.

In the controller:

`ViewBag.Title="Our house in the middle of a street";`

In the template:

`<h1>@Viewbag.Title</h1>`

If you the model is already available, just pass it as a property of ViewBag:

`ViewBag.SecondModel=myExistingModel;`